# What is the best way to encrypt my Windows user folder?

Tags: encryption, windows

I'm trying to encrypt my user folder on a Windows 10 shared machine.

I don't have Windows Pro, so EFS or BitLocker are no option. I can't encrypt or change the whole system since I'm not the only user.

I want to automatically decrypt and mount my files when I login, like what eCryptfs does on Linux ([Ubuntu's Encrypted Home documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) is based on eCryptfs).

Does Windows provide any sort for supporting encrypted user folders ? Do you know of any examples of such a configuration?

Comment: To clarify, you want to encrypt *only* your Windows user folder, and nothing else? That means you don't want `Full Disk Encryption`?

Comment: While the part of the question that asks for a product recommendation is off-topic for this site, I think the overall question about whether Windows supports individual encrypted user directories is on-topic.

Comment: I think your question fits SuperUser website

Comment: @Mark yes, exactly

Comment: @Neil do you think I should edit the question to be more general ?

Comment: @Begueradj yes, I will post it there too

Comment: @YdobEmos - I edited the question already to remove the product recommendation portion. Specific product recommendations are prohibited in most technical SE network sites. That said, someone may throw a product name into an answer to a more general question.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just setting the access setting to only allow yourself to read from it, or do you want to prevent a system administrator from reading form it as well?

Comment: Please do not cross post on StackExchange sites

Comment: I want to prevent someone with physical access to the computer from accessing my files, i.e. by booting on a Live USB system.

Comment: In that case, use Bitlocker's full disk encryption.

Comment: @Stephane I said in the question that I am not the only user and therefore I can't encrypt the whole disk. And that I don't have Windows 10 Pro, which prevents me from using BitLocker. I'm looking for something similar to eCryptfs, which don't seem to exist currently, given that neither Google nor the answers here gave me a solution. I think I will avoid putting personal data on this computer.

Comment: You have to define your threat model properly. When asked why you wanted to encrypt your user folder, you said "someone with physical access to the computer from accessing my files, i.e. by booting on a Live USB system". That is completely different from protecting your files from a user who already has (legal) access to your system

Comment: I want to protect my data from both. I keep the example of eCryptfs : when I'm not logged in, my files are encrypted. When I'm logged in and my folder is mounted, the other users cannot access my files because of the OS's ACLs. I though the two cases are not very different, because both the "legal" user and the Live USB user have physical access to the computer. So let's assume someone has physical access AND a legal, non-administrator account, and I want to prevent him from accessing my user folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use DiskCryptor. I don't think it can encrypt folders but it's very good at encrypting entire partitions. You can simply create a partition and use it as a folder and encrypt it using this free tool.

https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: OP only wants it for the user folder, though.

Comment: @MarkHulkalo yes I've mentioned that, but if he can always create a separate partition and use it as the encrypted folder. There's no real distinction if no other restrictions exist.

Comment: It's like 2 AM, so I missed that... my apologies.